# Is there a simple way to configure a Gradle plugin immediately if it exists or later if it's added?

Tags: gradle

I sometimes use `apply from: 'some/common/config.gradle'` and would like an easy way to configure a related plugin immediately if it already exists or to watch for it to be added and configure it later.  I can do what I want, but it seems a bit messy since I end up copy / pasting the config into two spots.  The below does what I want, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

```groovy
def configured = false;

if(plugins.hasPlugin(ApplicationPlugin)) {
    run.classpath.add(configurations.jfxrt)

    startScripts {
        mainClassName = "com.javafx.main.Main"

        doLast {
            logger.warn(":${project.name}:startScripts:!! WARNING !!" +
                    " Replaced mainClassName with com.javafx.main.Main")
        }
    }

    configured = true
}

else {
    plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
        if(plugins.hasPlugin(ApplicationPlugin) && !configured) {
            run.classpath.add(configurations.jfxrt)

            startScripts {
                mainClassName = "com.javafx.main.Main"

                doLast {
                    logger.warn(":${project.name}:startScripts:!! WARNING !!" +
                            " Replaced mainClassName with com.javafx.main.Main")
                }
            }

            configured = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to achieve this is `plugins.withType(ApplicationPlugin) { ... }`.

Comment: Yes, that does exactly what I want.  That's what I thought I should be doing from reading the API, but I must have made a stupid typo somewhere when I tried it.  Thanks for clearing it up for me.